# Add Data Frame to Excel in Specific Cell

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to write a pandas data frame to an excel spreadsheet. I am reading the excel workbook in from a template as the client wants a specific header, format, etc.

If I want to add the table starting at row 17, how do I modify the code below to achieve this? There are formatted, merged cells in rows 1 through 16 so when I try to save in current form it gives me `AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only`. I saw a similar stack question but respondents advised just adding a bunch of blank cells before adding the data frame--a solution that won't work for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook('proto_temp.xlsx')
ws_rq = wb["Results Query"]

rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws_rq.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save("df_to_xl.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:**
Is there data ***after*** row 17?

If **Answer** == **NO**, then see below

```py
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
```

If **Answer** == **YES**, then the answer is slightly more complicated.

**Options**

- Structure your code so you run the code above, *before* other cells are written below.
- Read XLSX into DF, make the changes and then write it back.
- Lastly, you could loop through a range and write cell-by-cell (feels too computationally expensive - but I figured I'd suggest it anyways). 
  `sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value = 2`

Hope this provides value :)

Comment: This was an incredibly helpful and concise response. Thank you very much :)